# Need Algorithm to create a auto code from a CSV file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, gawk

I have "N" columns in a csv file say Hardware,Sensors,Statistics(1,2,3 .....N) as shown below.

[image: CSV Data]

Each column has unique xml code that I need to generate with respect to the above table content.

```
<Hardware A>
   <Sensors sen1> 
        <Stat1>Mean</Stat1>
        <Stat2>Avg</Stat2>
        <Stat3>Slope</Stat3>
   </Sensors sen1>
   <Sensors sen2> 
        <Stat1>Min</Stat1>
        <Stat2>Max</Stat2>
        <Stat3>Mean</Stat3>
   </Sensors sen2>
    ....
    ....
</Hardware A>
```

I need to generate a code similar to above with respect to the table. Can anybody tell an Algorithm to implement this structure using SHELL SCRIPT

Comment: Don't show us a picture of a "csv file", show us the actual input file that we could run a tool against to test and the actual, precise associated output you'd want generated given that input file (i.e. do NOT put a bunch of `...`s in the output).

Comment: btw wrt `using SHELL SCRIPT` - the UNIX shell is just an environment to sequence calls to UNIX tools. The UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. So, I'm not sure what you mean by `using SHELL SCRIPT` but the way to do this in UNIX is to write an awk script to do it and just have the shell call awk.

Answer (score 2):

It'd be something like this in awk (untested obviously since you didn't provide testable sample input/output):

```
BEGIN { FS=","; fmt="%s %s>\n" }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        tagName[i] = $i
    }
    next
}
$1 != "" {
    if (prev != "") {
        printf "</"fmt, tagName[1], prev
    }
    printf "<"fmt, tagName[1], $1
    prev = $1
}
{
    printf "   <"fmt, tagName[2], $2
    for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {
        printf "      <%s>%s</%s>\n", tagName[i], $i, tagName[i]
    }
    printf "   </"fmt, tagName[2], $2
}
END {
    if (prev != "") {
        printf "</"fmt, tagName[1], prev
    }
}
```